# window.URL.createObjectURL fails to load the source of uploaded image and returns blob url

Tags: jquery, image-upload

I have uploaded an image and in `jquery`, I have stored that image source using

```
window.URL.createObjectURL()
```

method but after loading it returns blob URL and fails to save the source.

```
 var img = document.createElement("img");
 img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
```

Comment: Are you getting any security error?

Comment: Gah, "in jquery i have stored"

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="image" />
<img id="img" />

<script>
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
    alert(url);
    document.getElementById("img").src = url;
</script>
```

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ranganadh/Fy38L/1/)

Comment: After uploading an image i am getting an alert as blob:54d483c9-e9bd-4160-af12-3263d817990d.Instead of this blob url i need to get the image url.if i gave inspect element its showing the img src as failed to load the given url

Comment: blob url is location of file saved in that particular browser which you called by `window.URL.createObjectURL`. It can't be used in another browser! Which error are you getting exactly?

Comment: In the alert box i am getting the blob url as image src.Now i need to perform cropping on the image we uploaded and need to display the cropped image in a div in another page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41072/discussion-between-ranganadh-and-user2089987)

Answer (score 0):

**TRY** this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var loadImg=function(event){
      $('#frame').attr('src', URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
  };
</script>
```

```
<form>
  <input type="file" accept="image/" onchange="loadImg(event)">
  <br/>
  <img id="frame"  width="100px" height="100px"/>
</form>
```